# Android calendar provider schedules clock alarm automatically

Tags: java, android, shell, alarm, dumpsys

I am making an activity which gets the next alarm clock with the method `getNextAlarmClock()`. It works perfectly and shows as expected the earlier alarm clock set in the system (in my case from the stock MIUI clock app).

Now comes the problem:

I noticed that if I set the alarm clock for the next day that the alarm is set for today's midnight. But I don't have any alarm set before tomorrow, and this repeats every day (one day is midnight, one day is 7:50pm, one day is 11:50 pm) but at that hour nothing happens.

So being totally confused by my phone behavior I connected to `adb shell` and executed `dumpsys alarm` command. I found these lines in the output:

```
Batch{38cd120 num=1 start=298318940 end=298318940 flgs=0x3}:
    RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{5d9a2c9 type 0 when 1510599024750 com.android.providers.calendar}
      tag=*walarm*:com.android.providers.calendar.SCHEDULE_ALARM
      type=0 whenElapsed=+5h12m31s451ms when=2017-11-13 19:50:24
      window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
      Alarm clock:
        triggerTime=2017-11-13 19:50:24
        showIntent=null
      operation=PendingIntent{db9bdce: PendingIntentRecord{b3ec4ef com.android.providers.calendar broadcastIntent}}
```

So it seems that the android calendar provider fires an alarm clock every day, but no memos or events are in the calendar.

My questions are:

- Why the calendar provider fires this alarm? and why it is an alarm clock instead of a simple alarm?
- How can i remove all the future calls to this alarm?